# is there an easy way to update a **kwarg while querying? django

Tags: django, parameters, django-queryset, reusability, keyword-argument

I have a function like this...which helps me with code re-writing when calling out a query

```
def user_profile(self, **kwargs):
    default_fields = {
        'is_deleted': False,
        'is_staff': False,
        'is_active': False
    }
    kwargs.update(default_fields)

    return Profile.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

but let's say, if I don't want to add another new parameter into the function and I want to override the `is_staff` field sometimes *maybe out of 20 queries only 1 need `is_staff: True`.

Is an easy way?

I have thought of adding another parameter into the function to detect if `True / False` something like that which would work.

But I wonder if there's an even easier faster way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Here you can find more information about merge two dicts 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression#26853961

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def user_profile(self, **kwargs):
    default_fields = {
        'is_deleted': False,
        'is_staff': False,
        'is_active': False
    }
    default_fields.update(kwargs)

    return Profile.objects.filter(**default_fields)
```

Basically just turn your default_fields dict into the base dict so if you want to override 'is_staff', just pass is_staff via kwargs.